# SQL column name is keyword "category"

Tags: sql, oracle

This query works:

```
SELECT product_name, unit_price, order_due_date
FROM orders
FULL OUTER JOIN products ON orders.product_id = products.product_id
WHERE product_name = 'bun';
```

whereas this one throws an error:

> ORA-00936: "missing expression"

```
SELECT product_name, unit_price, order_due_date
FROM orders
FULL OUTER JOIN products ON orders.product_id = products.product_id
WHERE [category] = 'soft drink';
```

I can't figure what's wrong with the second

Comment: Oracle doesn't recognize the `[` and `]`.

Comment: You can use double quote in oracle : `WHERE "category" = 'soft drink';`

Comment: `category` is indeed a keyword, and for that reason it is a really bad idea to use it as a column name. However, the use of keywords (which are not `reserved` - a much shorter list) as column names is not illegal, and you can reference the column name without escaping it. You don't need square brackets or double quotes or anything like it (unless you did use double quotes when you created the table, in which case you must use double quotes AND match the original capitalization exactly when you use it in queries).

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple tables in a query, you should always qualify column names.  In your first query, the `WHERE` clause is undoing the `FULL JOIN`.  In fact, I am guessing that an `INNER JOIN` is most appropriate.  How would an order have a product not in the `products` table?

```
SELECT p.product_name, ?.unit_price, o.order_due_date
FROM orders o INNER JOIN
     products p
     ON o.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE p.product_name = 'bun';
```

As for your second query, `[` and `]` are not delimiters in Oracle.  Either leave them out:

```
WHERE category = 'soft drink'
```

Or, if for some obscure reason the column name actually has those characters, then use double quotes:

```
WHERE "[category]" = 'soft drink';
```